# How to Animate UIView embedded in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, uitableview, cakeyframeanimation

On `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, I am reloading selected row and changing `heightForRowAtIndexPath` so that selected tableview cell can expand. This is working fine. So as soon reloading expanding done I have to animate a UIView which is in the back of a UIImageView.

Animation should be like its coming from behind of imageView and stop at certain position like its revealing from image. It should be simple ? by changing y origin and doing in it animation block.

But the problem is its not at all animating with simple UIView beginAnimations code. I think it should be possible using CAKeyframeAnimation applying to the layer of UIView.

I have never played with layers. Can anybody guide me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
CABasicAnimation *myViewAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
[myViewAnimation setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(INITIAL_X,INITIAL_Y)]];
[myViewAnimation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(FINAL_X,FINAL_Y)]];
[myViewAnimation setDuration:0.5];
[myView.layer setPosition:CGPointMake(FINAL_X,FINAL_Y)];
[myView.layer addAnimation:myViewAnimation forKey:@"position"];
```

You'll need to link the QuartzCore framework to your project and import it (`#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`)